Laravel 11 API returns 404 on validation error
I have Laravel 11 API which works fine till the validation does not throw validation error 422. I would expect json response but Laravel somehow returns redirect and then html 404 not found. What should I set up to get json response also on validation error? Is there some settings in Laravel for it?
Thanks.

It would help if you would give us some sort of code. Maybe request/response dumps. What is the location of the redirect response?

You can force laravel to return json on api routes by using a middleware. To create a Middleware run php artisan make:middleware ForceJsonResponse. Now in ForceJsonResponse.php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ForceJsonResponse
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
        return $next($request);
    }
}

After that you need to add the middleware to the api group. In bootstrap/app.php
use App\Http\Middleware\ForceJsonResponse;

->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
    $middleware->api(prepend: [
        ForceJsonResponse::class,
    ]);
})

Adding a API fallback route is optional but I would recommend it
Route::fallback(function (){
    abort(404, 'API resource not found');
});

